# Installing the Numenta Platform

Tags: python

I want to install the Numenta Platform in Ubuntu12.4.

It created by python 2.5 and for Ubuntu 9.4.

You can see the installing step and requerment in the below link
[The Numenta installing help](http://www.numenta.com/archives/education/installing-nupic.php)

But in Ubuntu 12.4 we have the python 2.7 and upper so when I tried to play the Numenta Platform faced to this error:

```
ImportError: libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After I inserted this commands in .bashrc file to change the python path to my Platform folder:

```
NTA=$HOME/nta 
export PATH=$NTA/bin:$PATH 
export PYTHONPATH=$NTA/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

But faced to the recent error again. It seems that the Platform is using from python2.5 yet.
I don't know how can I run The Numenta Platform now.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Python2.5 via the DeadSnakes repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.5
```

Comment: Is any way that solve this problem without python 2.5?

Comment: I installed python2.5 but faced to that error again.What I have to do now?